# Can I combine method calls the use enums into a generic?

Tags: c#

I have the following method calls:

```
var types = CityTypeExt.GetOptions();
var statuses = CityStatusExt.GetOptions();
```

and the following methods:

```
public static class CityTypeExt
{
    public static SelectList GetOptions()
    {
        var values = EnumUtilities.GetSpacedOptions<CityType>();
        var options = new SelectList(values, "Value", "Text");
        return options;
    }
}

public static class CityStatusExt
{
    public static SelectList GetOptions()
    {
        var values = EnumUtilities.GetSpacedOptions<CityStatus>();
        var options = new SelectList(values, "Value", "Text");
        return options;
    }

}
```

Is there a way I could make a generic method that would combine CityTypeExt and CityStatusExt ?

Note that CityType and CityStatus are Enums.

Comment: Since [System.Enum.TryParse<TEnum>()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783499.aspx) uses enums like that, it must be possible in some way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
public static class CityExt
{
    public static SelectList GetOptions<T>() where T : struct, IConvertible

    {
        var values = EnumUtilities.GetSpacedOptions<T>();
        var options = new SelectList(values, "Value", "Text");
        return options;
    }

}

var types = CityExt.GetOptions<CityType>();
var statuses = CityExt.GetOptions<CityStatus>();
```

Comment: I suppose the GetSpacedOptions generic method has some constraints on the type parameter (probably T : Enum). You will have to duplicate those constraints in your method declaration.

Comment: @Artem - Are your method calls correct. Don't you mean to call CityExt ?